# How to get the information of a division after clicking a button in it in EJS

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am facing an issue in getting the data of a division while clicking a button inside that division. Basically, I am trying to show the details of `customers` in `cards` like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxafj.png) image.

I am fetching informations from postgresql using node js like

```
[
  {
    "name" : "demo",
    "email" : "demo@domain.com",
   ...
  }
]
```

So, when I click on the edit/delete button of any card, I'd like to get the `email` for that specific `customer`. Here I am posting the ejs file, that I have written.

```
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="<%= contactEndpoint %>">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <% for(var i = 0; i < customerData.length; i++) { %>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <p><%= customerData[i].name %></p>
                <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                <div id="id01" class="modal">
                    <form class="modal-content animate" action="http://localhost:3000/edit" method="post">
                        <div class="imgcontainer">
                            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <input type="email" value="<%= customerData[i].email %>" name="email" readonly="readonly" hidden/>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="phone">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="reminder frequency" name="remfreq">
                            <button type="submit">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
<script>
    // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

I have written `<input type="email" value="<%= customerData[i].email %>" name="email" readonly="readonly" hidden/>`, because I want to get the `email` of that `customer` without making this input box visible to the user. Here `customerData` is an array of objects which is fetched from postgresql using node js.

What can be done to achive my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a function with required parameters and call it on onClick.

```
<button onclick="someFunc(<%= customerData[i].email %>)" style="width:auto;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function someFunc(email) {
  modal.style.display='block';
  console.log(email)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But I want to pass the `email` in the `<input type="email" value="<%= customerData[i].email %>" name="email" readonly="readonly" hidden/>`, because these data will be available as a form data. So, I can perform any operation with it.